# checking if two arrays of integers have the same elements regardless of their order

Tags: c, arrays, struct, integer, compare

This code stores the values of the cards in `arr.value`.
Then I try to check if the elements in the arr.value have the same elements as the array `cmpvalues`.
If it an element doesn't match an element in the array `cmpvalues` it should print out "error" and return 0.
However even if the Input is correct it still prints out an error.
Everything compiles fine , I just can't find the bug.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXCOLR   14
#define MAXLINE  100
#define MAXCHR  1024   
#define _GNU_SOURCE

typedef struct {
    char color[MAXCOLR];
    int value;
} colorval_t;

int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b) {
   return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}


int main (int argc, char **argv) {

size_t n;
int cmpvalues [] = {
   65,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8,
    9,
   10,
   74,
   81,
   75,
   65,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8,
    9,
   10,
   74,
   81,
   75
};


    size_t ndx = 0;
    char buf[MAXCHR];
    colorval_t arr[MAXLINE] = {{ .color = "" }};

    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) { 
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    while (ndx < MAXLINE && fgets (buf, MAXCHR, fp)) {
        char c;
        if (sscanf (buf, "%13s %d", arr[ndx].color, &arr[ndx].value) == 2)
            ndx++;
        else if (sscanf (buf, "%13s %c", arr[ndx].color, &c) == 2) {
            arr[ndx].value = c;
            ndx++;
        }
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   

    for (size_t i = 0; i < ndx; i++)
        printf ("arr[%2zu] : %s %d\n", i, arr[i].color, arr[i].value);




 qsort(arr, 26, sizeof(arr[26]), cmpfunc);
 for( n = 0 ; n < 26; n++ ) {   
      printf("%d ", arr[n].value);
   }



    return 0;



}
```

input:

```
RED A
RED 2
RED 3
RED 4
RED 5
RED 6
RED 7
RED 8
RED 9
RED 10
RED J
RED Q
RED K
BLACK A
BLACK 2
BLACK 3
BLACK 4
BLACK 5
BLACK 6
BLACK 7
BLACK 8
BLACK 9
BLACK 10
BLACK J
BLACK Q
BLACK K
```

Comment: It is hard to understand, how your code should work. What do you expect this to do: `match = match ;` for example? (Hint: it's a noop)

Comment: A common way to test, if two lists contain exactly the same elements, is to sort both lists and then check them item by item.

Comment: @Ctx sorting would take a lot of time and I have no Idea how to sort array elements

Comment: look at `qsort()` and it is the fastest option you have.

Comment: @Ctx I uesed qsort() to sort the array but I keep getting a warning that qsort is implicit declared but everything works fine. Whats the best way to compare the two arrays now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Algorithm to check if two unsorted integer arrays have the same elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33068561/algorithm-to-check-if-two-unsorted-integer-arrays-have-the-same-elements)

Comment: Check each element if it matches the corresponding element at the same position in the other list

Answer (score 0):

Indenting the code properly shows the function does nothing and always returns `0` (unless `t1size == 0`).

```
int all_match( int table1, int table2 , size_t t1size, size_t t2size)
{
    for(size_t t1index = 0; t1index < t1size; t1index++)
    {
        int match = 0;
        for(size_t t2index = 0; t2index < t2size; t2index++)
        {
            match = match ;
            if(match)
            {
                break;          // never happens
            }
        }
        if(!match){
            printf("error");
            return 0;           // always happens
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Note that the arguments `table` and `table2` are ignored.

Comment: they are supposed to be arrays

Answer (score 0):

The following match function would do the trick:

```
int all_match( colorval_t *table1, colorval_t *table2 , size_t t1size, size_t t2size)
{
    for(size_t t1index = 0; t1index < t1size; t1index++)
    {
        for(size_t t2index = 0; t2index < t2size; t2index++)
        {
            if (table1[t1index].value==table2[t2index].value
            &&  strcmp(table1[t1index].color, table2[t2index].color)==0)
                break;
        }
        if (t2index >= t2size) {
            printf("error");
            return 0;
         }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: when I add it to my code and try to compile it I get many errors. like colorval has no member named colour

Comment: This method can fail if duplicates are permitted in the lists. A sort-and-compare method is faster and more accurate.

Comment: @momonosuke, ever heard of thinking for your self, like seeing that `colour` should be `color` or fixing a rogue brace?

Comment: @Ctx, the original card deck should not be sorted. The present order may have meaning. But in principle you are correct. The specification does not say the input is a single deck of cards. An additional field in the struct e.g. `checked`can solve that.